# c++, строка в цикле

Tags: c++, строки

Не могу понять, почему переменную типа string нельзя заключить в цикл? Выдаёт ошибку: "отсутствует оператор "<", соответствующий этим операндам". Код:

```
    string s;
    int i, kol;

    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    cin >> s;
    kol = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < s; i++)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Ну как вы  сравните что меньше:  5 или     "число какое то"?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что сравниваете метры с часами...

Хотя бы так.

```
for (int i = 1; i < stoi(s); i++)
```

Но лучше -

```
int s;
cin >> s;
for (int i = 1; i < s; i++)
{
```

И проверить, что все нормально введено. А то введет пользователь что-то типа "нафиг" (вы же в курсе, что `cin>>s;` читает не строку, а **слово**?), и что больше - нафиг или 5*?...

Comment: может ОП знаком [только с javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmEDA.jpg), где такие операции разрешены и [дают ожидаемые результаты](https://repl.it/repls/VisibleTinyVertex)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что язык С++ **строго типизированный** и сравнение строки и целого числа в нем не предусмотрено.

Нужно строку преобразовать в целое число сначала.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите, чтобы цикл выполнялся, пока `i < "какое-то число типа данных string"` (например, `string s = "5"`), то используйте `stoi(s)` (stoi - STring TO Int). Причем стоит добавить проверку на то, что пользователь именно число ввел, а не буквы. Если хотите, чтобы цикл выполнялся столько раз, сколько символов в S, используйте `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)`, где **s.length()** - длина строки S (и это выражение - уже INT). Как писали выше сравнивать можно только одни типы данных (int с int, string с string и т.д.). Не забудьте `#include <string>` и `using namespace std;`